# How rigid can a rigid object be in GR?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Consider a cubic lattice of space probes, with rocket motors and lasers to measure distance, and a clock to measure time. As they more from free space to the vicinity of some black hole, they try to move to keep the same distance from each other. However, they can't do that exactly, but what is the best they can do? Effectively the probes are defining their own spatial 3D coordinate system, which is as much like the cubic lattice as possible.

Alternatively, as is stated in the title, how rigid can a rigid object be in GR?

A bit of analysis leads me to the following guess, which is likely wrong, or at best true only infinitesimally. I am sure that there is a better answer already out there, and I am hoping that someone knows it.

I guess that the answer may be something like the following, for coordinates $x^1,x^2,x^3$ in an approximation to flat space (curvature `small'):

$g_{ii}$ can be chosen to be independent of $x^i$.

$g_{ij}$ can be chosen to be independent of $x_k$, for $i,j,k$ all different.

To be more specific, it seems that for a close approximation to Minkowski space, the rate of change of $g_{12,1}+g_{13,3}-g_{22,1}-g_{33,1}$ (and permutations thereof) is forced by the components $T_{0i}$ of the stress energy tensor.

This problem comes from considering the detailed initial setup of geodesic coordinates on a Lorentzian manifold.

Comment: It's very rare for spacetime to be non-rigid.  If you had a truly rigid object in an arbitrary GR spacetime, you would almost always expect the object to be shattered by the impossible metric relations forced on it by space-time. Or at best, it would be stuck, unable to move or rotate.  But that would be ignoring the physics that define the geometry of objects. If the object is reasonably flexible and the molecules it consists of did not have rigid metrical relations between them it would move more freely but aspects of its motion could be partially-determined by its rigidity.

Comment: I think this might be better over at physics overflow, but best to define what you mean first...    Brief answer: Rigidity is often stated to be impossible in special relativity, because if somebody hits one probe, it takes time for the signal at the speed of light to affect the others.  In GR, your question is a bit ambiguous.  You want a 3D lattice, but of course it is space-time that is curved, not just space.  Do you mean specifically a black hole space-time?  A black hole has space-time curvature without any stress-energy tensor.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous, but I was hoping that there was an existing body of literature, and I did not want to make it too restrictive.

Comment: There is a coordinate system which is formed by taking a 3D space like submanifold, and declaring it to be time zero, and then taking the geodesic motion in 4D perpendicular to the submanifold, with time coordinate proper time. This gives a nicely behaved coordinate system, at least locally. If we can start in flat space, and then move into more complicated geometry, we can set an initial metric on the 3D slice to be the usual Euclidian metric.

Comment: The problem is, what if we cannot start in flat space? What is the best that we can do with the coordinate system? The black hole is just an example of a localised curvature - the details are not important.

Comment: Is this your question? Given a general Lorentzian manifold, construct a family of hypersurfaces locally foliating the original manifold and orthogonal to a given timelike geodesic.  Using geodesic coordinates, it is clear we can make the 3-metric on these surfaces of the form $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+O(x^2)$.  For a given Riemann curvature tensor in the original manifold, how small can we make the quadratic correction terms by choice of hypersurfaces and coordinates?

Comment: That is a good way of thinking about it - and may well give a method for finding the answer.